# reactjs doc mentioned to deferred event in useEffect hook, what it means?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I was reading [reactjs doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects) about `useEffect` hook and they mentioned :

> the function passed to useEffect fires after layout and paint, during a deferred event.

can you explain what is deferred events is ? Is it a part of DOM core or what ?

Thanks...

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143623/what-are-deferred-callbacks

Comment: @Agney can you explain this in  Reactjs land with simple example referring to what called deferred event ?

Comment: deferred event is a JavaScript concept, which is why ReactJS docs does not go into explaining it. If you look for `javascript deferred events`, you can find a number of blogs and posts that explain the concept

Answer (score 4):

**In short**

`during a deferred event` that confused you only means: the function that you  pass to useEffect hook will not run immediately but run during an event which   will be fired later (after painting to be precise)

**In detail**

React under the hood works with the implementation of algorithms called Fiber. Which in a nutshell improves React's handling of asynchronous tasks and priorities.

Effects created by *useEffect* are internally called passive effects. Passive effects based on their order of definition in the function component are chained to each other using a next method and scheduled to run after each paint (not render).

> ```
> // This commit included a passive effect. These do not need to fire until
> // after the next paint. Schedule an callback to fire them in an async
> // event. To ensure serial execution, the callback will be flushed early if
> // we enter rootWithPendingPassiveEffects commit phase before then.
> ```

[You can checkout the implementation if you are interested.](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberScheduler.js)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question with a specific react use case:
You want to indicate your Progressive Web App is installable, and to provide a custom in-app install flow:

- Listen for the beforeinstallprompt event.
- Save the beforeinstallprompt event, so it can be used to trigger the install flow later.
- Alert the user that your PWA is installable, and provide a button or other element to start the in-app installation flow.

Here comes the defered: You may want to wait before showing the install prompt to the user so they are not distracted from what they are doing. For example, if the user is in a check-out flow or is creating his account we let them complete that before prompting
 them.

So a mini example of a deferred event

```
 let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => { 
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can install the PWA
  showInstallPromotion();
});
```

We provide an UI element the user clicks on using the deffered var

```
buttonInstall.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Hide the app provided install promotion
  hideMyInstallPromotion();
  // Show the install prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
      console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
    } else {
      console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
    }
  })
});
```

Hope this clears the fog a little.